# Increasing gif resolution in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, gif, dpi

I am making a Python matplotlib animation and I'd like to save it as a GIF, but the GIF resolution is too low. To compare the GIF resolution to my desired quality, I saved a single frame in PNG format. The result is much better, as you can see below:

[Animated GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZEUO.gif)

[PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70TwT.png)

Here is my plotting code for the PNG:

```
# Plot (PNG)

plt.style.use('dark_background')
plt.figure()
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, Lx), np.arange(0, Ly))
plt.contourf(X, Y, psisquare[3000, :, :], 100, cmap = plt.cm.viridis)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.title("Densité de probabilité à t = " + str(round(3000*dt,5)) + " s")
plt.savefig('2D_Schrodinger_Equation.png')
```

And plotting code for the GIF:

```
# Plot (GIF)

plt.style.use('dark_background')
fig = plt.figure()

def animate(k):
    k=k*100
    plt.clf()
    plt.pcolormesh(psisquare[k, :, :], cmap = plt.cm.viridis)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")
    plt.title(f"Densité de probabilité à t = {k*dt:.5f} s")
    return

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = int(Nbi/100), interval = 50, repeat = True)

writergif = animation.PillowWriter(fps=30)
anim.save("2D_Schrodinger_Equation.gif", writer=writergif)
```

How can I improve the GIF quality? Thank you.

Comment: You should provide the full code to make easier to anybody to test it

Comment: @Nathz, did changing the plt.figure() DPI solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think increasing the figure dpi will increase the dpi of the resulting animation. For improved quality try modifying your figure instantiation:

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi = 300)
```

You may also need to modify the end of your script with a call to the `animation.PillowWriter.setup()` method, and possibly also providing the `dpi` argument to the `animation.Animation.save()` method. Without your full code to attempt to reproduce, I can't be sure.

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = int(Nbi / 100), interval = 50, repeat = True)

writergif = animation.PillowWriter(fps = 30)

# fig.dpi is default dpi, but can also be specified explicitly if preferred
writergif.setup(fig, "2D_Schrodinger_Equation.gif", dpi = 300) 

# May or may not need to specify dpi argument
anim.save("2D_Schrodinger_Equation.gif", writer = writergif, dpi = "figure")
```

Check out the `setup` method in the `matplotlib.animation.PillowWriter` documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.PillowWriter.html#matplotlib.animation.PillowWriter.setup) and the `save` method in the matplotlib.animation.Animation documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.Animation.html#matplotlib.animation.Animation.save).